# How to hide particular CSS element in different screen size?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have the following CSS code and from that I'd like to remove only one element i.e. `max-width:40%` or make it `max-width:100%` in different screen sizes.

My CSS Code:

```
.extended-entry-left {
    max-width: 40%;
    float: left !important;
    line-height: 50px !important;
    text-shadow: 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    margin-bottom: 20px !important;
    margin-top: 20px !important;
    margin-right: 20px !important;
    margin-left: 20px !important;
    font-size: 38px;
}
```

I'm using the following @media queries but it's not working!

```
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    .extended-entry-left {
        min-width: 100% !important;
    }
}
```

Please help me!

Comment: Works fine. [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7tvg9hoe/). Also you probably don't need all them `!imporant`.

Comment: Incorrect screen width used?

Comment: @Ruddy and Math3w thank you very much for your reply. Problem solved!

In fact I was opening so much tabs in chrome that I had not re-sized my browser up to 400px. So I checked it in another browser and it was working absolutely fine. Thank you very much Guys!

Comment: But also, I don't know how to remove particular CSS element in different screen sizes. In the above instance, what should I do if I want to remove max-width:40%;  Thanks!

Comment: You can't technically remove the instance - you have to overwrite it. E.g. set it like so `max-width: none;` in the media query for that size.